# Extension of regular function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

This is an exercise in Hartshorne's book.

> For a quasi projective variety $Y$ with dimension $\geq 2$ and $p \in Y$ a normal point,
>   if $f$ is regular on $Y-\{p\}$ then $f$ can be extended to a regular function on $Y$.

I want to get some hints to prove this problem....

Comment: What part do you not understand? If you tell us, then you'll get better hints.

Answer (score 4):

Since the problem is local around $p$, you can assume that $Y=Spec(A)$ where $A$ is a noetherian domain  (quasi-projectiveness is irrelevant).

Clearly, every point $\mathfrak q \in Spec(A)$ of height one is distinct from $p$ (since $\mathfrak q$ it corresponds to a subvariety of codimension $1$). So every function $f$ defined  on $Spec(A)\setminus \lbrace p\rbrace $ is defined  at $\mathfrak q $.
You can  then conclude that $f\in A$, that is $f$ extends regularly through $p$, thanks to the formula valid for a noetherian normal domain  (Matsumura, *Commutative ring theory*, Theorem 11.5, page 81)

$$ A=\bigcap_{ht(\mathfrak q)=1}    A_ \mathfrak q              $$

A general result in this vein is that if $X$ is a locally noetherian *normal* integral scheme and $Y\subset X$  a closed subset of codimension $\geq 2$, the restriction morphism $\mathcal O_X(X)\to O_X(X\setminus F)$ is bijective.

Comment: Thank Georges, But, This problem is one of exercise of Hartshorne's book "Algebraic geometry" chapterI.1.3.... Maybe there is s proof with out scheme theory...??

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg : Could you please show me where to find the proof of the above general result ?

Comment: @Arsenaler Do you know the proof of this problem? Thanks.